# How to forward/route eth0 to specified as0t0 client? (Internet to VPNetwork's Client)

Tags: internet, vpn, iptables, port-forwarding

I have a VPN server which connected to the internet over eth0. And VPNetwork's device is as0t0/as0t1. I have a specified VPN Client which i want to reach it over internet over VPN Server's public Internet IP(x.x.x.x).

I want to reach VPN Client over 7777 port over Pure Internet, but it is behind the NAT.
I want that:
When i connect to the x.x.x.x:7777, it must be routed to the VPN Client's same port.

I have tried somethings using iptables. But didn't worked. Is it true way?
If yes, what must i do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to DNAT from Public IP Address to client IP address in VPN network. Assume your public IP is `1.1.1.1` and client IP address is `192.168.1.50`, use following command:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 1.1.1.1 --dport 7777 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.50
```

Be sure that client's default gateway is your VPN server.